# Import a typescript file into a nodejs CLI script

Tags: node.js, typescript, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a script to wrap up some existing TypeScript functionality. For example, my folder structure looks like

```
./src/library.ts
./scripts/runner.ts
```

I have a custom ts config file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "importHelpers": false,
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": ["test"]
}
```

The script test.ts is as follows

```
import yargs from "yargs"
import library from "../src/library"

library(1);
```

The library file is below

```
const library = (c: number) => {
  console.log(2);
};

export default library;
```

I invoke it as follows

```
npx tsc --project tsconfig-scripts.json; node build/scripts/test.js
```

I get the following error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Following the instruction to add "type": "module" to package.json gives the following error.

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/gregreynolds/src/Development/orchestra-slackbot/build/src/library'
```

Checking the build folder does show that the module is indeed in the place that it is expected to be.

Is there any way to run this script? None of the examples I have found are of this exact use case.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague answered this for me. This TS Config file works if you *do not* have "type": "module" in package.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "importHelpers": false,
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": ["test"]
}
```